# blockOverlay class style override in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

There is this class that gets added into the cart totals in the checkout process to signify updates being made as the user is inputting relevant information such as a shipping address. When that happens, the class `blockOverlay` appears with inline styles. I'm attempting to override those styles, or edit them somehow. Anyone knows where I can tweak the CSS for that element? I can't override inline styles with my external wordpress stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can over-ride inline styles by using `!important`. Just add `!important` after specifying each property for the styles of `blockOverlay` element inside your stylesheet like this:

```
.blockOverlay {
     width: auto !important;
     display: block !important;
     //so on...
}
```

Here's an example:

```css
.blockOverlay {
  background: red !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockOverlay" style="height: 100px; width: 500px; background: blue;"></div>
```